# Adding Basic authentication params to HttpSolrClient using invariantParams

Tags: solrj

I am trying to write a SOLR client using SolrJ HttpSolrClient.
I have to use Basic Authentication.

The documentation for SolrJ HttpSolrClient says that there is:

```
protected ModifiableSolrParams invariantParams
```

and the description is:

Parameters that are added to every request regardless. This may be a place to add something like an authentication token.

Can someone who has used this before please tell me how to use the invariantParams for basic auth?

```
public class MySolrClient extends HttpSolrClient{

    private String hostUrl;

    private String userName;

    private String password;

    public CloudForgeProcurementSolrClient(final String hostUrl, final String userName, final String password) {
        super(hostUrl);
        this.hostUrl = hostUrl;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        if (invariantParams == null) {
            invariantParams = new ModifiableSolrParams();
        }
        //        invariantParams.add(arg0, arg1);
    }
}
```

What should be arg0 and arg1 be in my case.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
            "myusername","mypassword");
    provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);                
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();     

    HttpSolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient(solrCoreUrl, client);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code:

```
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new 
UsernamePasswordCredentials(username,password);
provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();

HttpSolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder()
            .withBaseSolrUrl(host)
            .withHttpClient(client).build();
```